# Ruby String ASCII operation?

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to do some ASCII options in Ruby, like what we did in Cpp?

```
char *s = "test string";
for(int i = 0 ; i < strlen(s) ; i++) printf("%c",s[i]);
// expected output: vguv"uvtkpi
```

How do I achieve a similar goal in Ruby? From some research I think `String.each_byte` might help here, but I'm thinking to use high order programming (something like `Array.map`) to translate the string directly, without using an explicit `for` loop.

The task I'm trying to solve: Referring to [this page](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/map.html), I'm trying to solve it using Ruby, and it seems a character-by-character translation is needed to apply to the string.

Comment: Why? We very seldom need to operate at that level in Ruby, so it sounds like you're trying to accomplish something in a very C++ way that we'd do entirely differently in Ruby. Explain what data you're working with, and why, and we can probably show you the Ruby way to do it, not show you the C++ way to do it in Ruby.

Comment: @theTinMan Tin Man Thanks for asking about the purpose. I updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pay close attention to the hint given by the question in [the Challenge](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/map.html), then use [String's `tr`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-tr) method:

```
"test string".tr('a-z', 'c-zab')
# => "vguv uvtkpi"
```

An additional hint to solve the problem is, you should only be processing characters. Punctuation and spaces should be left alone.

Use the above `tr` on the string in [the Python Challenge](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/map.html), and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Nice solution, Sn, even if you wanted to convert the space: `tr('a-z ', 'c-zab\"')`

Comment: It's not necessary to escape the double-quote when it's enclosed in single quotes: `' '.tr(' ', '"') # => "\""`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`String#each_char`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-each_char) and [`String#ord`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-ord) and [`Integer#chr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Integer.html#method-i-chr):

```
s = "test string"
s.each_char.map { |ch| (ch.ord + 2).chr }.join
# => "vguv\"uvtkpi"
```

or [`String#each_byte`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-each_byte):

```
s.each_byte.map { |b| (b + 2).chr }.join
# => "vguv\"uvtkpi"
```

or [`String#next`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-next):

```
s.each_char.map { |ch| ch.next.next }.join
# => "vguv\"uvtkpi"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use codepoints or each_codepoint methods, for example:

```
old_string = 'test something'
new_string = ''

old_string.each_codepoint {|x| new_string << (x+2).chr}

p new_string #=> "vguv\"uqogvjkpi"
```